# what does "the rearing, reeling of silk" mean?

Tags: meaning

There is a part of the advertisement:

> Education and enjoyment go hand in hand so at th Lullingstone Silk Farm witness **the unique rearing, reeling and production of English silk**, as supplied to royalty.

I have looked up the word **rearing**

> 1 the process of caring for children as they grow up, teaching them how to behave as members of society
>
> 2 the process of breeding animals or birds and caring for them as they
>   grow

Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 9th edition © Oxford University Press, 2015
There is no result related to material and the word **reeling** is also hard to understand. 
By the way, why did the writer use **as supplied to royalty** but not *as a supply to royalty*.

Comment: 'As supplied to royalty' is a conventional way of saying that members of a Royal Family have bought silk from the farm. It doesn't necessarily mean that the farm is the main supplier of silk to the monarchy.

Comment: @KateBunting It may also mean that the business has a Royal Warrant, but a quick scan of the register shows that to not currently be the case.

Comment: @SGR I think they would put 'By Royal Appointment' if they had a warrant. NB I wrote _a_ Royal family on purpose; the customer could have been a foreign royal for all we know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

what does “the rearing, reeling of silk” mean? Raising silk worms and harvesting the silk:

**rearing**:  [def of rearing as in animal husbandry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/rear)

> bring up, care for, look after, nurture, parent
>
> (of an animal) care for (its young) until they are fully grown.

**reeling**: [reeled silk](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reeled_silk)

> Silk made from entire cocoons, as distinguished from lower-quality
>   silk made by spinning short fibres obtained from broken cocoons and
>   other silk waste.